# Problem regarding density and specific weight

Tags: density

> The density, or more precisely, the volumetric mass density, of a
>   substance is its mass **per unit volume.**
>
> The specific weight is the weight **per unit volume** of a material.

Does that mean density and specific weight are the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, weight is mass times gravity ($g$). 
So  for a mass $M$ in a volume $V$
$$\textrm{density}=M/V$$
whereas
$$\mathrm{specific\;weight} = Mg/V = \textrm{density} \cdot \textrm{gravity} \ (g)$$

Answer (score 1):

> **Note:** Mass is constant for an object but weight varies with gravity, weight= mass*gravitational acceleration. So **density in constant but specific weight is not**.

Volumetric mass density of a substance is its **mass per unit volume**.
 
Density is expressed by 
$$\rho = M/V$$
where, $\rho$-density, $M$ -mass, $V$-volume

SI unit of density= $\mathrm{kg/m^3}$

[Specific weight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_weight) is  the weight per unit volume of a material.

It is given by $$\gamma=\rho\cdot g$$
where, $\rho$-density,  $g$ - acceleration due to gravity

SI unit of specific weight= $\mathrm{kN/m^3}$